# Cell ControlTemplate binding to AttachedProperty binding to property of view model

Tags: wpf, datagrid, attached-properties

Suppose I have a datagrid whose binded objects are of type ObjectVM:

```
  Public Class ObjectVM
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Property NestedObject As New NestedVM

End Class
```

And NestedVM is defined as:

```
 Public Class NestedVM
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _SubValue As Double
    Private _Value As Double

    Public Property Value As Double
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Value = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SubValue As Double
        Get
            Return _SubValue
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _SubValue = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubValue"))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I've defined a `datagridtextcolumn` where the `cellstyle`'s template has been overridden to contain a second TextBlock.  I want the main text of the column to bind to the (nested) property `Value`, and the second TextBlock to bind to the (nested) property `SubValue`.  To accomplish this an attached property `NumberSource` (of type Double) has been added to GridColumnProperties.  Inside the custom controltemplate, the second Textblock is binded to this NumberSource, and the NumberSource is in turn binded to SubValue:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NestedObject.Value}" local:GridColumnProperties.NumberSource="{Binding NestedObject.SubValue}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

However this only seems to work if NumberSource is set to a literal value; it fails when NumberSource is binded like above.  Here is the current attached property definition:

```
Public NotInheritable Class GridColumnProperties
Private Sub New()
End Sub
Public Shared ReadOnly NumberSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NumberSource", GetType(Double), GetType(GridColumnProperties), New PropertyMetadata())

Public Shared Sub SetNumberSource(obj As DependencyObject, value As Double)
    obj.SetValue(NumberSourceProperty, value)
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetNumberSource(obj As DependencyObject) As Double
    Return CType(obj.GetValue(NumberSourceProperty), Double)
End Function
```

End Class

How can I get the dependency property to correctly bind to `SubValue`?

Comment: Do you need to reuse the same template in different columns?

Comment: Yes that is my intention.

Comment: BTW, `static` in C# is equivalent to `Shared` in VB.Net, instead of `NotInheritable`.

Comment: Thanks good to know.  That was run through an internet code converter.  Feel free to answer in C# if you wish.

Comment: Actually turns out you can't declare `Shared` on class level in VB.Net, so the converter instead declares `Shared` on all class methods, which is probably the closest approximation possible.

Comment: I think a static class would be similar to a VB.Net `Module`.

Comment: The problem is that these things should be modeled at the ViewModel level. Instead of doing attached properties and so on, create a ViewModel capable of showing different values in the same property, then you can have the TextBlock inside the `Template` bound to a specific property.

Comment: "different values in the same property"... not sure I understand, but is that not what I'm doing by having a nested object in the VM, that can show both `Value` and another `SubValue`?  How would I bind the TextBlock in the `Template`, such that the template could be reused for multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then the different columns should all have their  respective ViewModel of this same type, and just put a `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SubValue}"/>` inside the DataTemplate. See what I mean?

Comment: I get `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SubValue' property not found on 'object' ''ObjectVM' (HashCode=49754846)'`  It looks like it's looking for `SubValue` inside of `ObjectVM`, instead of `NestedVM`.

Comment: then change the binding to `{Binding NestedObject.SubValue}`

Comment: okay so you are not talking about inside the definition of the `ControlTemplate` in the `Resources` section, since `NestedObject` is a specific instance of `NestedVM`.

Comment: I'm truly very sorry to not be getting this, but in my setup, the `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}"/>` code is inside the `<ControlTemplate>` code inside resources section of the window.  I don't see how I could set TextBox binding there to `NestedObject`, because now that template would not be resuable for multiple columns... imagine that the final version of `ObjectVM` would have lots of `NestedVM`'s binded to lots of columns that all use this single template.