# Require reusable DataCell ControlTemplate for different binding sources

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, styles

(Visual Studio 2010)  From web examples, I have overridden the `ControlTemplate` of a `DatagridTextColumn` to include an additional Image binded to the ViewModel.

```
   <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Grid  Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Regular" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Duration="0" To="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Name="FocusVisual" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#66FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" />

                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" />

                        <Image Source="{Binding someProperty}" Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFDC000C" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Rectangle Name="RightGridLine" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1" />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

The line of interest is near the bottom: `<Image Source="{Binding someProperty}" Grid.Column="1"/>`.  I want to be able to reuse this `ControlTemplate` in several places within the application.  The only difference will be the binding paths of the `Column` itself and this added `Image`.  Ideally I could then declare a `TextColumn` and declare this style and direct the bindings with minimal additional code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding typicalProperty}"
                    CellStyle="myStyle" 
                    [this part can't do -->] ImageSourceBinding="{Binding anyPropertyInViewModel}" >
```

I've come across multiple posts of users asking how to create a reusable `ControlTemplate`, or `TemplateColumn`, or `Style`, for columns of the `DataGrid` using different binding paths, and so no far no one seems to have provided an answer on how to do it.  A common suggestion is to try an `AttachedProperty` but the binding doesn't work right.

Surely there has to be a better approach than to copy/paste all that above code for each individual column, then change the binding path?  To my mind that would be utterly ridiculous, and completely flies in the face of all I've ever learned about the concept of coding redundancy... what if your column count is dozens, or even hundreds?  As it stands this is a severe limitation of the customability of the `DataGrid`... I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need to add in your data class property, for example - `AnotherTextValue`. For example, we have a class `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string BaseValue
    {
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    // value for TextBlock in DataGridCell
    public string AnotherTextValue 
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }
}
```

`ObservableCollection` of this class:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Objects 
{
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

Style of `DataGridCell` is desirable to place the resource of windows (Window.Resources), or in `App.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        ...
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

`TextBlock` in `DataGridCell` style will look like this:

```
...
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding AnotherTextValue}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Define `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding BaseValue}" Header="My Super Header" />
```

Comment: Yes I think you understand the basic idea.  But what if I have *lots* of columns with this style in the datagrid, but each column's `TextBlock` has a specific binding path (not always `AnotherTextValue`).  Is there a way to use `MyCellStyle` over and over again, only with different binding paths for the `TextBlock`?

Comment: @Tekito: Yes, I understand. I'm trying to make this behavior by using the attached dependency properties, but I have not yet working. If this works out, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you.  By the way, I also experimented with creating attached properties on the column, but it only worked when I supplied a literal value.  I couldn't get the attached property to bind to a property of the view model. But I am new to WPF, so maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687305/cell-controltemplate-binding-to-attachedproperty-binding-to-property-of-view-mod  - that's the link to an earlier attempt using attached properties.  I was also trying to use nested objects:  every column is bound to an object that has a `Value` and `SubValue` property, so the main cell text binds to `Value` and the additional `TextBlock` binds to `SubValue`.  But nested or not, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Tekito: I tried to create its attached dependency property on C#, but I did not succeed. And I'll try describe my process (just want to say, I could be wrong). The fact that my property has been successfully created, and takes values through `DataGridTextColumn`, but when I try to set this value in `DataGridCell` style via `TemplateBinding` (or another method), meaning nothing is transmitted, although the value for the property is successfully is set. Perhaps, in the style of `DataGridCell` can only be value of `DataContext`. At the moment, I can advise to use a method from my example.

Comment: Yeah I had similar problems, no matter how I attempted to set bindings it seemed source was never transmitted.  So are you saying if I use this style with multiple columns, I'll just have to copy/paste the entire `cellstyle` code, with different `textblock` binding path?

Comment: @Tekito: If we have the same problems occur... Perhaps, you may have to dig in direction as you say: `different textblock binding path`. Or think of an alternative solution that does not depend on the `DataGridCell` style, but it would be up to your specific goals.